# MIPS move command

Tags: assembly, mips32

I am new to MIPS so wanted to know if the move command removes the value from the original register in which it was stored?
For eg. move $t1, $v0
Value in $vo will be copied or entirely moved to $t1?

Comment: A MIPS instruction-set reference specifies every effect each instruction has on the architectural state.  That doesn't include modifying the source register, for fairly obvious reasons.  (It would be extra work, an extra register write, and normally undesirable for programmers / compilers.)

Answer (score 1):

The mips `move` instructions are more accurately `copy` instructions. The source register is untouched by `move`

Note that `move` is a pseudo-instruction, provided by the assembler. It's not present in the hardware.

See [https://www.dsi.unive.it/~gasparetto/materials/MIPS_Instruction_Set.pdf](https://www.dsi.unive.it/%7Egasparetto/materials/MIPS_Instruction_Set.pdf)